# Which version of the .NET Framework will SDL Web 8.5 support?

Tags: web8

I found this documentation page, but it is for version 8.1.1: [.NET assembly templating client prerequisites](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-A44B85B6-0CF8-40AF-9A66-C897D470CCC4)

Do we already know which .NET Framework (e.g. 4.5.2 or 4.6.2) SDL Web 8.5 will support?

Comment: I've rewritten your question to it's a bit easier to read and understand. Hopefully I have kept the meaning behind your question; if not, I apologize. It was just not very legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.5.2 will be *deprecated* in SDL Web 8.5 and .NET 4.6.2 will be *supported*. That means you can use either version but we recommend that you use the newer 4.6.2.

This applies to both the Content Manager and Content Delivery.

Comment: This was documented a few days after this question was posted: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-4C8490C8-2476-4E0D-BF73-F0274E2ED772